# Datetime format causing error?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I'm using bootstrap datetimepicker which allows user to select date.
But when I run it in different laptops i get different format for the date.

For example in my laptop when i run the app and check the value that is being passed in my post method i get something like this

```
8/27/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

but when i run the app in someone else's laptop i get this value in the post method

```
1-1-0001 00:00:00
```

this results to **invalid modelstate** in my controller's post method. 
I have no idea why this is happening. Can someone give me some suggestion and how can I solve this issue and make the datetime format always look like `8/27/2013 12:00:00 AM` post method?

Here is the code in view

```
<div id="datetimepicker2" class="input-append date">
                <input name="DateEntered" type="text"/>
                <span class="add-on">
                    <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
                </span>

            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({

                        language: 'en',
                        pick12HourFormat: true
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: Were the laptops running the same OS and were you using the same browser?

Comment: yep, windows 8 and chrome as browser

Comment: Have you tried adding an explicit format to the options like so `format: 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'`?

Comment: where do i do that? in my view model?

Comment: No on the client side with the plugin, I'll post an answer with it.

Answer (score 0):

'Try setting the format for the datetimepicker explicitly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
            language: 'en',
            pick12HourFormat: true,
            format: 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'
        });
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

Try tagging the view model property or action method argument with the `DisplayFormat` attribute:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss}")]
```

Comment: when i check on chrome's developers tool, the value it is passing as a post method is like i want, but when i check the controller's post method and inspect the data, the datetime value is not what is being passed from server